# Please name this plant

Tags: species-identification, botany

[image]

What is the name of this plant? It was found in a village in Bangladesh, in the month of February.

Comment: Where was this plant found and what time of year?

Comment: From a village of  Bangladesh, in the month of February.

Comment: @FaysalAhmed Add this info (and as much else you can think of) to the actual question (use the edit button).

Comment: @FaysalAhmed Don't copy the posted answer(s) to the question. It makes the Q-A pair impossible to understand for future readers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe this plant may be *Rotala rotundifolia*

Quoting from Wikipedia,

> It is a common weed in rice paddies and wet places in India, China, Taiwan, Thailand, Laos, and Vietnam, and has been introduced to the United States.

This makes sense, as Bangladesh is located near both India and China.

> The emerse form has rounded leaves, the submerse leaves are narrow lanceolate. It is very variable dependent on light and environmental conditions. Under strong light, the leaves can become almost wine red. It has pale pink flowers.

[image]

[image]
([source](https://houseaqua.ru/uploads/posts/2012-06/thumbs/1338886860_rotala-kruglolistnaya_2.jpg))